# Spring + JPA + H2 Strange behaviours of lazy fetch and bidirectional OneToMany

Tags: spring, jpa, lazy-loading, h2, one-to-many

I have been playing for a long time with JPA, in the past through EJBs, now with Spring. I have recently noticed some weird behaviours I can hardly explain.

**First the bidirectionnal OneToMany**
My bidirectional OneToMany is correctly set with a mappedBy.

```
@Entity
public class EntityOne {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "one")
    private Set<EntityTwo> twos;
...


@Entity
public class EntityTwo {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    @ManyToOne
    private EntityOne one;
...
```

Then this does not update the database :

```
@Transactional
public void firstWay(){
    EntityOne e1=em.find(EntityOne.class,1);
    EntityTwo e2=em.find(EntityTwo.class,1);
    e1.getTwos().add(e2);
}
```

while this does :

```
@Transactional
public void secondWay(){
    EntityOne e1=em.find(EntityOne.class,1);
    EntityTwo e2=em.find(EntityTwo.class,1);
    e2.setOne(e1);
}
```

I am quite puzzled...

**Then the lazy fetch :**

```
   // this is just a tool example...
     public void someFindBy() { 
        EntityOne e1=em.find(EntityOne.class,1);
        for (EntityTwo e2:e1.getTwos()) {
            System.out.println(e2);
        }
    }
```

leads to LazyExceptionError... Shouldn't my "e1" entity remain attached until the end of the method and thus hibernate resolve the fetch (I use the default persistence context ,i.e. Transaction scoped. **I did also try to make the method transactional by annotating it with @Transactional but that didn't change anything**).
So, well, I could use an Entity Graph or a Join Fetch, but, still, I wonder why it doesn't work as is...

Here is the Spring configuration file :

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"facade"})
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class ClientWebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {


    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder builder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder();
        EmbeddedDatabase db = builder
                .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
                .build();
        return db;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em
                = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "model" });

        JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());

        return em;
    }

    Properties additionalProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop");
        properties.setProperty(
                "hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files" ,"insert-data.sql");
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(
            EntityManagerFactory emf){
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);

        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation(){
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

}
```

Comment: The first part is normal behavior as the attribute „one“ is the owner of the relationship.

Comment: The lazy part is also normal as long as you method is not transactional.

Comment: Well, coming back to this question and to my code some months later, it occurs that the lazyexception has vanished... (I did not even had to add cascade, nor orphanremoval, nor lazy in the OneToMany tag...). What did happend I don't know, only change my jdk to 14 and cannot figure out how it could have it...

Answer (score 0):

fix this entity.

cascade, fetch must be set to update.

```
@Entity
public class EntityOne {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    **@OneToMany(mappedBy = "one", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)**
    private Set<EntityTwo> twos;
```